# Compiling Tetri Duel Kernel Raspberry Pi

Tags: arm, kernel, tetris

So I#m totally stuck on
compiling this kernel https://github.com/Tetris-Duel-Team/Tetris-Duel for Raspberry Pi.
The Assemble Script seems not to work under Ubuntu 12.04 and I have no clue how compiling with
gcc arm is working.
Any Guides or Answers?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was part of the Tetris Duel Team. 
We have just uploaded binaries for linux so that you can compile it on Ubuntu.
If you have any further questions, you can email us directly - all our emails are on github.

Thanks for noticing our project!;)